# Calculate product price from several fees

Tags: magento-2.1, price

My products have a base price, but each product can have additional fees, like costs for the packaging or for special delivery conditions (Dangerous Goods Fee). How can I calculate the final product price dynamically by using all my costs?

Christian

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a `sales.xml` file under `<NAMESPACE>/<MODULE_NAME>/etc` folder and add the below code over there.

   ```
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Sales:etc/sales.xsd">
   <section name="quote">
       <group name="totals">
           <item name="customer_discount" instance="<NAMESPACE>\<MODULE_NAME>\Model\Total\Quote\<CLASS_NAME>" sort_order="420"/>
       </group>
   </section>
   ```
2. Now create the class on the above mention path.

   ```
   namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Total\Quote;

   class CLASS_NAME extends \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\AbstractTotal
   {

   protected $priceCurrency;

   public function __construct(
           \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency
       ) {
           $this->priceCurrency = $priceCurrency;
           $this->setCode('customer_discount');
       }

   public function collect(
           \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
           \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
           \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
       ) {
       $address = $shippingAssignment->getShipping()->getAddress();
       if ($address->getAddressType() != 'shipping') {
           return $this;
       }
       parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);
       $baseDiscount = 10;
       $discount = 10;
       $total->addTotalAmount('customer_discount', -$discount);
       $total->addBaseTotalAmount('customer_discount', -$baseDiscount);
       return $this;
   }

   public function fetch(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote, \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total) {
       if ($quote->getActualMycardDiscount()) {
           $data = [
           'code' => 'customer_discount',
           'title' => 'customer discount',
           'value' => 10
           ];
           return $data;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. You need to generate dynamic value for `$baseDiscount` and `$discount`.

Comment: I want to explain more what I need.
I have added two price attributes:
cost_packaging and cost_transport_dangerous_good. No I want to us as product price: 
price + cost_packaging + cost_transport_dangerous_good. This calculated price should be used for the whole order process and should replace the default product price